# Select only features within the layout view

Tags: arcgis-10.0, select

I want to create a [tool layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002100000039000000) in ArcGIS10 that will select only features within the current layout view so that I can add the attribute table to the layout and only show attributes for the selected features.

Has anyone got any ideas on how to do this?  I want the selection to be done automatically each time the mxd is opened, and not have to do it manually.

Comment: Some terms in your question need to be explained/clarified: "tool layer" = script tool?, "dataframe" = extent?, "layout window" = layout view?, "workspace" = map document? Without clarity, potential answerers have to guess these things.

Comment: Fair point - I've come to Arc from Mapinfo and still use some of the Mapinfo terms.  I've edited accordingly.  A tool layer is not a script tool though, it is a tool that has been placed on the table of contents and is run each time the mxd is opened.

Comment: I see, never played with those myself. http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002100000039000000